# mvc api does not reach Controller get method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple api written in MVC 4,when i run it write the address,it does not reach the controller:

here is my controller:

```
 public   IEnumerable<tenMinsStatcs> Get()
    {

       string id="192.168.39.32";
        string dttimeFrom="05082019";
        string dttimeTo="08082019";
        string format = "ddMMyyyy";
        DateTime fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact(dttimeFrom, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime todate = DateTime.ParseExact(dttimeTo, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


        TestClasscs ts = new TestClasscs();
        ts.m_turbine_id = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.39.82");
        ts.m_time_stamp = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-08-07 5:20:30");
        ts.m_wind_speed = 5;
        ts.norm_wind_max = 3;
        ts.norm_wind_min = 2;
        ts.norm_wind_speed = 3;
        ts.norm_wind_speed_without_ntf = 1;


        List<TestClasscs> myTur = new List<TestClasscs>();
        myTur.Add(ts);

        // mm.m_time_stamp = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-08-07");
        //// mm.m_turbine_id = "192.168.39.84";
        // tst.Add(mm);



        IPAddress turip = IPAddress.Parse(id);
        // var rslt = _context.tenmins.Where(s => s.m_turbine_id ==turip && s.m_time_stamp >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).Take(2).ToList();

        var rslt = (from m in _context.stat10

                    where m.m_turbine_id == turip && m.m_time_stamp >= fromdate && m.m_time_stamp <= todate
                    select new tenMinsStatcs

                    {
                        m_time_stamp = m.m_time_stamp,
                        // m_turbine_id = m.m_turbine_id.ToString(),
                        m_wind_speed = m.m_wind_speed



                    }).ToList();
        return rslt;
    }
```

here is my webApiConfig:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
        // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
        // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();

        // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
        // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
```

any idea where im doing wrong?
when I run my code, after localhost i write api/Values ,considering this it should reach the controller right?

Comment: can you tell us how you are calling that API method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change configuration in RouteConfig.cs file in which routes patterns as defined and ASP.Net MVC routes request as per below cofiguration. api literal prefix only in Web API not for MVC action method why you are appending api litteral after host name. ASP.Net MVC action method can be execute when you type URL- HTTP sheme://domain name:port/litteral/Controller Name/Action Name

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```